# Python to get related software names

Tags: python, nltk

I have an excel sheet which contains many software names such as Visual studio 2012, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2017, Adobe Reader English, Adobe Reader Deutsche, Power shell 4.0 , Power shell 2.0, Power Shell 5.0.

I would like to get only one related software version name. For example in this case I want my output to be Visual studio 2013, Power shell 4.0, Adobe Reader English alone and leave the rest. I'm using Python NLP. I have removed all the junk characters and Version number but I'm not sure how to proceed further.

Any ideas to build further? I tried sequence match after getting two software names without any numbers and junk characters, however the result is not accurate and efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\533471\\Desktop\\Book2.csv', encoding='Windows-1252')
saved_column = df.RowLabels[:]
second_column = df.RowLabels[:]

print(saved_column)

for eachcol in saved_column:
    eachword = eachcol.split()
    print(eachword)

    for secondcol in second_column:
        sentence = None
        wordo = None
        punct = None

        x = []
        copy = []
        secondword = secondcol.split()[:]

        ####proceed only if the first word is equal
        if eachword[0] in secondword[0]:
            print("true")
            sentence = eachword[:]
            sentence += secondword

            ####splitting according to punctuations.
            for token in sentence:
                word = wordpunct_tokenize(token)

                if wordo is None:
                    wordo = word
                else:
                    wordo += word

            ####Removing all the punctuations.
            punct = [item for item in wordo if item.isalpha()]
            t = punct[:]
            t.reverse()

            for p in punct:
                print(p)
                if len(x) > 0:
                    print(x, "Appended")
                    a = str(p)
                    x += [p]
                    if p == x[0]:
                        break
                else:
                    print("list is empty")

                    x += [p]

            x.pop()
            for z in t:
                print(z)
                if len(copy) > 0:
                    print(copy, "appended")

                    copy += [z]
                    if z == punct[0]:
                        break
                else:
                    print("list is empty")
                    copy += [z]

                print(copy)

        else:
            print("false")
```

Comment: Your indent is all messed up.